# Why does QSqlError parameter count mismatch?

Tags: c++, qt

I'm making a small app that connects to SQLite DB. I have created a `QSqlDatabase` and it is connected. But when I run the `QSqlQuery`, I get the parameter count mismatch. The query is executed when a button is pressed. The function is called "insertPressed".

mainwindow.cpp:
This is the setup function. The DB is initialized in this function.

```
MainWindow::MainWindow(QWidget *parent)
    : QMainWindow(parent)
    , ui(new Ui::MainWindow)
{
    ui->setupUi(this);
    db = QSqlDatabase::addDatabase("QSQLITE");
    db.setHostName("localhost");
    db.setPort(3306);
    db.setUserName("username");
    db.setPassword("password");
    db.setDatabaseName("qt");
    db.open();

    if(db.open()){
        ui->Success->setText("Connected to Database");
    } else {
        ui->Success->setText("Connection Failed");
        qDebug() << db.lastError();
    }
    QPushButton *select = MainWindow::findChild<QPushButton *>("SelectFile");
    connect(select, SIGNAL(released()), this, SLOT(selectPressed()));

    QPushButton *insert = MainWindow::findChild<QPushButton *>("Insert");
    connect(insert, SIGNAL(released()), this, SLOT(insertPressed()));

    QPushButton *deleteRecord = MainWindow::findChild<QPushButton *>("Delete");
    connect(deleteRecord, SIGNAL(released()), this, SLOT(deletePressed()));
}
```

insertPressed:

```
    QString line;
    int i = 0;
    QFile file(fileName);
    if (!file.open(QFile::ReadOnly | QFile::Text)){
        QMessageBox::warning(this, "Error", "No file opened");
        ui->SelectFileLabel->setText("Select File First");
        return;
    }
    QTextStream in(&file);
    QSqlQuery query(db);
    while(!in.atEnd()){
        line = in.readLine();
        stringlist = line.split(QLatin1Char(','));
        for (int j = 0; j<stringlist.size(); ++j){
            ui->FileContent->appendPlainText(stringlist[j]);
        }
        query.prepare("INSERT INTO orders(Time, Source, Acct, Trader, Dest, Exe, Qty, Price, Status, Side, Sym, Tif, Routing, SenderPID, Date) VALUES(:time, :source, :acct, :trader, :dest, :exe, :qty, :price, :status, :side, :sym, :tif, :routing, :senderpid, :date)");
        query.bindValue(":time", stringlist[0]);
        query.bindValue(":source", stringlist[1]);
        query.bindValue(":acct", stringlist[2]);
        query.bindValue(":trader", stringlist[3]);
        query.bindValue(":dest", stringlist[4]);
        query.bindValue(":exe", stringlist[5]);
        query.bindValue(":qty", stringlist[6]);
        query.bindValue(":price", stringlist[7]);
        query.bindValue(":status", stringlist[8]);
        query.bindValue(":side", stringlist[9]);
        query.bindValue(":sym", stringlist[10]);
        query.bindValue(":tif", stringlist[11]);
        query.bindValue(":routing", stringlist[12]);
        query.bindValue(":senderpid", stringlist[13]);
        query.bindValue(":date", stringlist[14]);
        if (query.exec()){
            ui->QueryStatus->setText("Query Executed");
        } else {
            ui->QueryStatus->setText("Query not executed");
            qDebug() << query.lastError();
        }
        i++;
    }


    file.close();
```

This is what the output looks like:

```
QSqlError("", "Parameter count mismatch", "")
QSqlError("", "Parameter count mismatch", "")
QSqlError("", "Parameter count mismatch", "")
QSqlError("", "Parameter count mismatch", "")
QSqlError("", "Parameter count mismatch", "")
QSqlError("", "Parameter count mismatch", "")
```

Comment: What kind of type are the fields in the table  "order" ? Are they all String/Text type ? Because using query.bindValue(":date", stringlist[14]); will try to bind :date as a string value, not as date.

Comment: They are all strings as they are copied straight over from a text file. I'm no good at SQL so I don't really know if I can store the date as a string or not.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So I solved the problem. I had not made a create table query before making INSERT query and that was causing the problem. Before the INSERT query I added the following lines.

```
        if (!query.exec("CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS orders(time TIME(0) NOT NULL, source VARCHAR(20) NOT NULL, acct VARCHAR(20) NOT NULL, trader VARCHAR(20) NOT NULL, \
                    dest VARCHAR(20) NOT NULL, exe INT NOT NULL, qty INT NOT NULL, price DOUBLE(5, 2) NOT NULL, status VARCHAR(20) NOT NULL, side VARCHAR(20) NOT NULL,\
                    sym VARCHAR(50) NOT NULL, tif VARCHAR(20) NOT NULL, routing VARCHAR(50) NOT NULL, senderpid VARCHAR(20) NOT NULL, date DATE)")){
            qDebug() << query.lastError();
    }
```

This fixed the error in my case.